# Package java swing application as rpm package for red hat?

Tags: java, swing, installation, rpm, deb

I have created installer of my java application for ubantu means debian based system.

I have 2 choices to distribute the package on rpm based sytem:

1. By converting .deb (debian) package into rpm and install it on red-hat.
2. creating .rpm package using rpm-tools.

By selecting first choice, I did:

```
  alien -r Mydeb.deb
```

output for above command create Mydeb.rpm package.

which convert .deb to rpm but when I was going to install it then
 issue occured after installing.

**Package can not be loaded javecodec:52 could not find.**

**How I can pack .jar with DB folder with embedded jvm in linux**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General question. So here comes general answer: https://fedorahosted.org/released/javapackages/doc/